# Wordpress Echo post count

Tags: php, wordpress, slug

I have a custom post type with multiple attributes within it,
such as price
color make model, etc.

Which is would like Wordpress to print the amount of posts within them.

my current code is this

```
 // Get total number of posts in "vehiclestock" post type
$count_vehiclestock = wp_count_posts('listings');
$total_vehiclestock = $count_vehiclestock->publish;
echo $total_vehiclestock . ' listings. ';
```

I've attached some examples to better explain myself.
as I am unaware of what to search for to answer my own question

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add This Code for count all post or category wise count post

```
$args = array(
      'posts_per_page' => -1,
      'post_type'=> 'post',
      'tax_query' => array(
                          array(
                              'taxonomy' => 'category',
                              'field'    => 'slug',
                              'terms'    => 'category_slug'
                          )
                      ),
    ); 
 $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );

 $post_count = $wp_query->post_count;
```

Comment: where exactly would i put the slug i want for it to grab the number of posts from?

Comment: is this correct? if so. its displaying nothing. not even a 0

`$args = array(
      'posts_per_page' => -1,
      'post_type'=> 'listings',
      'tax_query' => array(
                          array(
                              'taxonomy' => 'location',
                              'field'    => 'slug',
                              'terms'    => 'toronto'
                          )
                      ),
    ); 
 $wp_query = new WP_Query( $args );

 $post_count = $wp_query->post_count;`

Comment: any assign post for "toronto" slug ?

Comment: Yes just 1 post

Comment: echo of post like "echo $post_count;"